# install GLPI application with sql server 2008 or Oracle 11g

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I want to install GLPI with sql server 2008 or Oracle 11g.

I already know that GLPI uses mysql.

Is it possible to install GLPI with sql server 2008 or Oracle 11g ?

Comment: This question is probably off-topic for this site, but according to the latest [GLPI documentation](https://forge.indepnet.net/daily-doc/glpidoc-0.83-en-2012-11-10.pdf) the answer is no, it only supports MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

GLPI Manual : Currently, only MySQL database server and MariaDB database server are supported by GLPI (MyISAM engine).